# Output analogue audio (via speakers) through "line in" jack

Tags: sound, alsa, speakers, jack, audio-jack

...So I've been using Ubuntu for about 6 months now since I switched from Windows. I've been searching for one specific feature that was missing for Ubuntu...

In Windows I used to connect my headphone and speakers to two jacks, one is a normal analogue audio output jack and the other was a line-in jack. I was able to make it output analogue audio via a software called "Realtek HD Audio Manager" but this software doesn't have a Linux version. It's so bad that I have to get up every time I need to switch between my devices since I'm limited to one jack.

Bottom line, the question is; how do I output analogue audio from my "line-in" jack? I need an alternative software to that mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I happened to stumble upon the solution [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/turn-headphone-jack-microphone-jack-ubuntu)!

A respectful developer named David Henningsson created an awesome tiny software that does the job!!! Even though it's still in the experimental phase up to the point but I installed it and it worked!!!! FINALLY!!!!!!!!

[image: The program]

...Now here's how to use it. It should be pre-installed but if not then follow [this](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/universe/a/alsa-tools-gui/install.html) and install it. ...To cut short the installation command is

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

Then just search for `HDAJackRetask`. You'd find it in your dash or if you use LXDE you'd find it under the "others" title in the menu and that's all!! :)

*p.s: "Apply now" didn't work. What worked was "Set as boot default"* ...still not bad at all XD